# rails - js.coffee files - bad performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, rendering

I have a home page rendering a lot of stuff and also a link in it that re-renders a small part of the page.

A full get request gives:

```
Completed 200 OK in 344ms (Views: 110.2ms | ActiveRecord: 10.0ms)
```

and the ajax link request:

```
Completed 200 OK in 2566ms (Views: 2356.1ms | ActiveRecord: 10.5ms)
```

and specifically:

```
Rendered application_pages/home.js.coffee (2352.7ms)
```

The home.js.coffee has three `if` in `<% %>` to decide what to render. Nothing complex, nothing heavy.

`UPDATE 1`

My home.js.coffee looks like this:

```
<% if params[:foo]=='foo1' %>
$('#aaa').html('<%= j(render(partial: "foos/foo1"))%>')
<% elsif params[:foo] == 'foo2' %>
$('#ccc').html('<%= j(render(partial: "foos/foo2"))%>')
<% end %>
```

Any idea? Is there any setting I'm missing?

Comment: No, nothing at all! The `ifs` are checking variables already set by the controller action.

Comment: show the .js.erb or coffee code, or maybe because its coffee

Comment: what is in your partials?

Comment: Is it recompiling your CoffeeScript for every request? Presumably Rails must deal with the ERB then convert the CoffeeScript to JavaScript and then finally send it back, each of those steps has a cost...

Comment: @muistooshort how else could I implement this?

Comment: Generally you separate your code and data so that you don't have ERB and CoffeeScript mixed together, then the server can just send some data back to the browser and the browser can do things with that data.